# Different master template for specific route

Tags: angular

This is my app.component.html, my main app template:

```
<md-sidenav-layout class="sidenav-primary" fullscreen>

<md-sidenav #start  mode="side" align="start" opened>
<div class="sidenav-menu">
<sidebar></sidebar>
</div>
</md-sidenav>

<main-menu></main-menu>

<div class="sidenav-primary-content">
<div class="container-fluid">

<div *ngIf="!Service.LOADED" class="text-center">
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>

</div>
</md-sidenav-layout>

<!--In case the user is not logged in, show the intro page-->
<div *ngIf="Service.LOADED && !Service.userData">
<intro></intro>
</div>
```

My problem is: I don't want to show the sidenavs and the main menu when the user is not logged in (when I output my `<intro></intro>`).

Do I really need to create a new module and route just to output the intro without the main menu & sidenav? I've been trying `*ngIf` and it's impossible above a `<router-outlet>`.

If creating a new module & route is the only option, can you be more descriptive about how my app structure should be like?

Thanks!

Comment: but you need to create a flag/boolean for your ngIf condition whether the user is logged in or not.So something like *ngIf="userIsLoggedin=true" then show the sidenav or whatever.

Comment: just asked almost this exact question before seeing yours, did you end up with a decent solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233639/specify-a-different-root-component-for-specific-route