# Specify a different root component for specific route

Tags: angular

Have an app with a root app component containing the site menu/basic layout. I would like to add a section (a few routes/components) that would use a different root component (not show the menu, etc).

I've created a new module but not sure where to go from here, is there a way to do this without blowing up the initial layout?

Edit: after posting I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128220/different-master-template-for-specific-route?rq=1) very similar question, though it has no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can break the your components in to a structure which can be more manageable. I have done something similar where I have public pages with a different header and private pages with a different one. To achieve that you can create modules and then configure routes for those modules or try something similar to the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: rootCommonComponent, //with some common logic
    children: [
       {
       path: '', component: publicHeaderComponent, 
           children: [
                     { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
                     { path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent }
                    ]
       },
       {
         path: '', component: dashboardHeaderComponent, 
           children: [
                    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
                    { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent}
                    ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

The above solution can work out in a single module. However, to have more manageable code I would suggest to break things down into module.

Comment: so basically what is currently in my root app.component would be moved into publicHeaderComponent and I would do whatever else in dashboardHeaderComponent?

Comment: yes, you can have different logic and template in dashboardHeader as compared to publicHeader. You can keep the root for some common business logic such as session token creation for api or multi lingual configurations.